# How do I position a division to the right side of the window?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue making #bgimage align to the right of the window

```
<header id="header" style="
">

<img id="bgimage" src="http://**.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/sparkler-test.png" style="position: absolute; float: right;display: block;">

<div id="site-title" style="position: absolute; clear: none;">
<a href="http://**.com/" rel="home">
<img src="http://**.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/LOGO-5.0.jpg" alt="" width="369" height="66" style="position: absolute;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't combine `position:absolute` and `float`. Use one or the other. If you choose `position:absolute`, make sure to add `right:0` and be careful of content going behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is probably what you're looking for.

```
position: absolute; right:0; display:block;
```

You may want to specify a width also, since block elements will by default take the full width of their container.

Also, I noted the ID is bgimage, are you trying to set a background?  If so, you can do that with the CSS `background` or `background-image` property.